# Why I cannot craft premium versions of some cards?

Tags: gwent

For some reason I cannot craft or transmute premium versions of some cards. For example, I cannot do it with Glustyworp:

No transmute option for regular card that I have:
[image]

And no craft option for premium card that I'm missing:
[image]

I have 10k scraps and almost 2k meteorite powder, I think that should be enough for crafting one card!

How can I craft such cards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Glustyworp is a Thronebreaker expansion card. You can craft the base card with scraps, but for the premium version you have to buy Thronebreaker and find the corresponding hidden chest in that game to unlock the card in Gwent. In the deck builder, you can filter cards by expansion at the bottom right corner to find all Thronebreaker cards.

Thronebreaker cards also cost 4 times the scrap to craft than the normal ones (e.g. the Glustyworp base card costs 800 instead of 200 for a regular epic to craft), if you don't unlock them by buying Thronebreaker.

[Here](https://guides.gamepressure.com/thronebreaker-the-witcher-tales/guide.asp?ID=46950) is a map guide of the chest locations.

One thing to note is, that there is also currently what I assume to be a bug, that prevents you from transmuting starting cards. These are cards are automatically unlocked for every player and cannot be milled. Since transmuting mills a card and gives you the premium isntead, the transmute button is currently missing on these cards. You can filter for these at the bottom right corner of the deck builder as well. This means, that you can currently only unlock the premium version by using scraps. Since getting premium cards for scraps [will be permanently disabled](https://www.playgwent.com/en/news/25048/upcoming-changes-to-gwents-economy-and-full-mill-value-refund-policy) on January 2nd, this is probably not intentional, but in the current version, transmuting these cards is not possible.

Full list of Thronebreaker cards that can't be transmuted:

- Kertullis
- Barnabas Beckenbauer
- Xavier Lemmens
- Dagur Two Blades
- Lippy Gudmund
- Ivo of Belhaven
- Gabor Zigrin
- Reynard Odo
- Glustyworp
- Count Caldwell
- Isbell of Hagge
- Gimpy Gerwin
- Eyck of Denesle
- Gascon
- Black Rayla
- Elf and Onion Soup
- Traeahern var Vdyffir
- Prince Villem
- Strays of Spalla
- Bomb Heaver